# SQL LIKE not working

Tags: java, sql, xml, jsp

I know this has been asked before but I can't understand how mine is not working.

I have tried

```
" WHERE REFERENCE_NUM LIKE '%'"+ whereClause+"'%'";
" WHERE REFERENCE_NUM LIKE '%1%'";
" WHERE REFERENCE_NUM LIKE '1%'";
```

and several others. now i know this part is where the issue is because if i change it to

```
" WHERE REFERENCE_NUM = " + whereClause;
```

or

```
" WHERE REFERENCE_NUM = 1000";
```

it returns the correct data. i am at a complete loss.

the reason it is setout like so is because i am following the instructions in the book "Dynamic web Application Development using XML and Java" by David parsons at UNI. however im an external student.

```
    String bigWhereClause = "WHERE REFERENCE_NUM LIKE '1%'";
        Collection<Accom> accomAll = ModelFacade.getAccoms(bigWhereClause);

        numbeOfResults = accomAll.size();
        return accomAll;



   public static Collection<Accom> getAccoms(String whereClause){
    //if no 'where' clause is given create an empty string
    if(whereClause == null)
    {
        whereClause = new String();
    }
    AccomDAO adao = new AccomDAO();
    Collection<Accom> accomCollection = adao.readAccoms(whereClause);
    return accomCollection;
}



public Collection<Accom> readAccoms(String whereClaws){
    Collection<Accom> accoms = new ArrayList<Accom>();

    try{
        //connect to DB
        getConnection();
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ACCOM" + whereClaws);
        //setup for the accom
        int reference = 0;
        String type = null;
        String walkDistance = null;
        String descrip = null;
        String contact = "defult";

        Accom accom = null;
        //repeat this while there is data in the results.
        while(results.next()){
            //resets accom item to new.
            accom = new Accom();

            reference = results.getInt("REFERENCE_NUM");
            type = results.getString("ACCOM_TYPE");
            walkDistance = results.getString("WALKING_DISTANCE");
            descrip = results.getString("DESCRIPTION");
            contact = results.getString("CONTACT");

            //sets the accom item with found details
            accom.setContact(contact);
            accom.setDescrip(descrip);
            accom.setReference(reference);
            accom.setType(type);
            accom.setWalkDistance(walkDistance);



            //adds accom item to list of accoms
            accoms.add(accom);
        }
        //bit of clean up on databse connection and results.
        results.close();
        results = null;
        statement.close();
        statement = null;
        connection.close();
        connection = null;

    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        cleanUp();
    }

    //returns what ever is found
    return accoms;
```

Comment: Can you show us output of the results, both good and bad? And an example of the data?

Comment: I dont think so, because that is only the parameter name.

Comment: Have you tied without the single quotes? You certainly don't need them around each % like `'%'`...

Comment: looks like your `REFERENCE_NUM` column has a Numeric data type

Comment: Just use a convert/cast/concat (depends on your dbms) on REFERENCE_NUM to make it a (n)varchar. Then you don't have a problem with the like.

Comment: this is what is returned when it's set to WHERE REFERENCE_NUM = 1000.
(this is the data)
1000  null Three bed room; Norman Garden area; Internet Access; Price: $300 per week.


it just returns nothing, not even an error, when i change it to WHERE REFERENCE_NUM LIKE %1%

Comment: i take that back i get this "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: No authorized routine named 'LIKE' of type 'FUNCTION' having compatible arguments was found."

Comment: Yes that was the issue. it was a numeric data type. i was unaware i am unable to use a LIKE for numeric

Answer (score 1):

Im not very sure but your SQL statement maybe has a space issur. Take a look the statement:

```
  ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ACCOM" + whereClaws);
```

Imagine after ACCOM you add the where condition as your example it could be like

```
  SELECT * FROM ACCOM WHERE REFERENCE_NUM LIKE '1%'
```

as I say already not very sure it is the cause but you can just give a spase like

```
  ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ACCOM " + whereClaws);
```

Good luck

Comment: that was not the issue at all. it just wouldn't let me search for numeric data. with a LIKE function. as i stated that same function and code worked just fine if i switched it from LIKE to =.

if  = 1 wasn't working as well then sure that's okay to point out but as i stated = 1 worker but LIKE 1% didn't in any way.

Comment: What is the type of fields you want to run the LIKE statement?
Check if the field type and the value you pass in Java is the same.

Comment: cha solved my issue. don't worry about it. the issue was about data types. you can not use LIKE on a table that is numeric. it was set as a big int. the problem has been solved.